# Communication frameworks summary

Tags: .net, wcf, protocols, communication

I'm a beginner in C# and .Net framework and I have been through the WCF chapter in my book.

On the other hand it's still not clear what communication frameworks exist beside WCF.

Does WCF cover everything?

I tried to find a good website summarizing the protocols(both synchronous and asynchronous), the communication layers used and their advantages, disadvantages, but I couldn't find any!

I was looking for something that you look at and you see all the ways computers communicate to each other.

I wouldn't need to know redundant technologies, but a nice high level overview to understand the big picture would be nice.

I know there are layers where data travels:

- HTTP and TCP

and message formats like:

- SOAP,
- XML
- JSON(REST?)
- binary

but I'm sure it's not all, and i'm missing a bunch.

Can somebody help me out? An existing website/image, etc. is perfectly fine if such exists.

Thank you!

Comment: as soon as you stop drinking alcohol everything will become clear :)

Comment: Lol thanks Leo! I really just want to see the big picture, nothing else. You are given a bunch of LEGO, but you don't know what piece to choose to build a starship. This is how I feel!!

Comment: Found something on a Microsoft site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
So ASP.Net and WCF should cover it all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So ASP.Net and WCF should cover it all?

Speaking very generally, yes.

Specifically, there are actively used communication stacks which are not WCF/WebApi based, including

- [Azure Service Bus](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/service-bus/)
- [Azure Storage Queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh767287.aspx)
- [Sql Server Service Broker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx)
- [System.Messaging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [BizTalk Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/server-cloud/products/biztalk/)

There are also many, many third-party open source communications products, including

- [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/)
- [NServiceBus](http://particular.net/nservicebus)
- [Akka.Net](http://getakka.net/)
- [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html)

Additionally, the Microsoft stack has communications capabilities which even though are older, are still in use, including

- [ASMX](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/308359)
- [.Net remoting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)
- [Msmq COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa926097.aspx)
- [DCOM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958799.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Tom, this answers my question(any way to mark this as an answer?), so basically it is too much to bring them down and compare under one umbrella, but if I want to stay with .NET both WCF and ASP.Net should cover my needs. What I need now is just an overview of these two, which should be easy to find. Thanks again!

Comment: @Soni no probs. In answer to your question, you just click the little tick thing next the question until it turns green.

Comment: @Soni as a general rule, when you need to use HTTP/REST, use WebApi. HTTP/SOAP, TCP, Named Pipes, MSMQ use WCF